# SendinBlue API to kick off Automation

Tags: php, api, sendinblue

Been banging my head over this, basically I have workflow setup on Sendinblue, starts off with a filling in of a form and begins the if and else however I wanted to upload a CSV to website, send its data over the API and let it kick off the work flow but to zero avail. All I have right now is the PHP script to upload a CSV, read it and then how do I send over this information for the Automation workflow to begin ? Nothing on Automation in their docs